# Checking TLSv1.3 support using openssl

Tags: bash, tls1.3

I'm using openssl to check if there is tlsv1.3 support or not over the list of domains. I've write the script but the script doesn't get stopped its waits for me to press CTRL+D than it gives me a result.
here is the scirpt

```
!/usr/bin/env bash

filename='domains.txt'
while read line;do
domain=$line

if openssl s_client -connect $domain:443 -tls1_3 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'Protocol  : TLSv1.3'; then
  echo "tls V 1.3 being used "
else
 echo "tls v 1.3 not begin used"
fi
done <$filename
```

I've also used echo with openssl like this

```
echo "x" | openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -tls1_3 2>/dev/null | grep  'Protocol  : TLSv1.3'
```

**NOTE:**
When i run the command on terminal for individual site i get the result without typing CRTL+D but when i used it in script using loop and if statement its waits for me to press CTRL+D. Its really strange.

I've also tried echo "q" | openssl command

Comment: Try `openssl s_client [arguments] </dev/null 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Another way is using `nmap`: `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 IP | grep TLSv1.3`

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more i've write this command as:
openssl s_client [-connect www.example.com:443 -tls1_3] </dev/null 2>/dev/null | grep 'Protocol  :  TLSv1.3'
but i didn't get any result

Comment: @dibery i can use nmap but its very slow as compared to openssl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like:

```
echo Q | timeout 1 openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -tls1_3 2>/dev/null
```

Passing `Q` will make it quit fast, and when can't connect `timeout` will make it quit.

Comment: This is not working when in write the same line in a script. I've to press CTRL+D and the result is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

thanks this works for me. Actually, when I'm using grep it gives me a false result without grep it works perfectly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in `cat domain.txt`; do 
echo $i
if echo Q | timeout 3 openssl s_client -connect $i:443 -tls1_3 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "$i" "tlsv1.3 enabled" >>output.txt
else
echo "$i" "tlsv1.3 disabled" >>output.txt
fi
done
```